# Encrypted iphone backup file has 16gb, but cannot see any files on in

Tags: iphone, backup, encryption

My iphone backup folder on my windows computer (in the AppData ->  ...-> MobileSync -> Backup folder) is of size 16gb. The backup is encrypted and I do know the password. However, when I try to use recovery-programs, they say that the backup is empty. Could anyone help be obtain the pictures in the encrypted backupfile?

Answer (score 2):

Does the backup have the Manifest.plist and Manifest.db files in it? Those contain the encryption-key data that's required to read an encrypted backup.

Sadly, since these files are written last during the backup, they're often missing in an incomplete encrypted backup, making whatever files are there useless due to the missing key data.

(Disclaimer: I'm a developer for one of these iPhone backup recovery programs, Decipher Backup Browser.)

Comment: Yes, it does have the Manifest.plist and Manifest.db files in it! 

But does that mean that even though the backup is of size 16GB, the data in there is most likely useless?

Comment: If it has the manifests, then you hopefully will be in luck. I can't vouch for the other backup reading software, but you can see if the free version of the software I work on is able to read it? https://deciphertools.com/download-decipher-backup-browser.html